Get Excel SheetNames using apache hop
How to Get Excel Sheet Names using Apache Hop? Is there any plugin that does this?
I used set variables, but I couldn't get the result. I need this name to transform into a field in my data processing pipeline. Are there specific settings or steps required to successfully capture sheet names in Apache Hop?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

the Excel Input transform does not support variables or fields for the sheet names. The only way to dynamically set sheet names at the moment is through metadata injection.
Feel free to create a feature request for this in the project's GitHub issues.
